# Laravel sync 2 databases bidirectional

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, synchronization

I'm building an application hosted on a central server with a database. However, I would like to be able to run the application on a second server that might be online but could be running offline. This server is a laptop; you won't know if it can connect to the internet. The databases must be synced once the computer connects to the internet again (or sync live as long as there is a connection).

I've looked at other posts, and they all talked about syncing one way while I need to sync bidirectional.

One option would be to keep track of changes, sync to the central server, and download the changes from there as long as a connection is possible. This could cause issues with incremental IDs. I could solve this with UUID, but we're talking about many tables with many rows that do not necessarily all need UUIDs, so this might be overkill. Also, I would have to build my application/database structure from the ground up to support UUIDs and then change the old rows to get a new UUID (given the amount of relationships, not an easy task)

There are also tools to sync databases automatically. However, I think these would have the same problem and might not work well without a connection.

What is the best way to handle a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll have to create a manual sync process.
There's no need to track changes, as long as you check the fields `created_at` and `updated_at` before overwriting any existing records, thus making sure you only overwrite with newer data.
Pseudo code:

```
for table in database_server_A:
    records = select * from table
    for record in records:  
         if not exists(record) in database_server_B:
             insert_into_database_server_B(record)
             continue
         server_b_record = select_from_database_server_b(record)
         if record.updated_at > server_b_record.updated_at:
             update_database_server_b(record)
         elif record.created_at > server_b_record.created_at:
             update_database_server_b(record)
```

Repeat the same by inverting server A and server B and you're done.
This will probably take a toll on performance, you could of course improve that code to only select records by `created_at` time which is higher than the last time a sync was done in order to speed things up.